# Error; Could not find or load main class (Java using Windows CMD)

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I am trying to compile and run some java files I have made in Eclipse. The full path to the .java file is `C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Java\Introduction\src\tests\Test.java`. `tests` is the package I created in Eclipse and `src` is a folder that Eclipse made under `Introduction` (which is the project name).

In my environment variables, I have the following relevant variable:

`JAVA_HOME` `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin`

Under system variables I have the following:

`CLASSPATH` `%JAVA_HOME%`

I go to my cmd and `cd` into the `tests` directory (`cd C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Java\Introduction\src\tests`). Then I compile using `javac Test.java`. This seems to work as I then have a `Test.class` file under the same directory. Now I want to run the file, I type `java Test` and I get the error, "could not find or load main class". I've tried a variety of things including appending `.class` and `.java` to the end but I keep getting the error. I looked at some answers and docs and I managed to get it to work if I `cd` into:

`cd C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Java\Introduction\src` (i.e, get out of the package)

and then run:

`java -cp . tests.Test`

So that seems to temporarily set the class path to the current directory, and run Test from the package `tests`. However, I want to simply be able to type `java Test`. I know it's possible as I used to be able to do it, but now for some reason I cannot (I must have changed something along the way...).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post code of Test.java as well

Comment: If your class Test is in a tests package then you need to run it with `tests.Test`. If your class `Test` is not in a package then you can run it without the package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I want to simply be able to type `java Test`

That will *only* work if `Test` is in the default package - it's as simple as that. You need to pass the `java` executable the fully-qualified name of the class you want to launch. There's no way round that.

Of course, you could create your *own* launcher which looks in the current directory for class files, finds out the fully-qualified name of the classes within those files, and launches `java` providing the full name and probably specifying an appropriate classpath... but that seems like a lot of hassle compared with just including the package name in the command.

Comment: So is it then possible to type `java tests.Test`? I have tried that whilst in the `tests` directory, and in the `src` directory and neither seem to work.

Comment: @Keir: I thought you said that did work in the src directory. If you have to specify the classpath, that suggests you may have an unhelpful CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is I have to specify the classpath for it to work. I figured there was a problem with my environment variables so I added it to my question - I'm not well versed with this!

Comment: @Keir: Get rid of the environment variable entirely.

Comment: I have removed the CLASSPATH variable (I still have the JAVA_HOME variable) and this does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Ahh it seems the environment variables settings don't save until you exit the window. Thanks for the help. Is there a reason why I don't need to use the fully qualified name for `javac`?

Comment: @Keir: You're passing filenames to javac, not class names.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Upvoted and selected as best answer :) .

Answer (score 2):

You could be making the same mistake I made. So, try the following.

Here is my code for your reference.

```
class A{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Once you saved this as "C:\JavaStudy\ClassA.java", try the following.

```
c:\JavaStudy>javac ClassA.java
c:\JavaStudy>java A.class
Error: Could not find or load main class A.class
c:\JavaStudy>java A
Hello world
c:\JavaStudy>
```

Note: You don't need to use " java.exe -cp . " if you have class file in the same directory from where you are executing.